# FileZilla から SFTP で Amazon EC2 に接続できない

Tags: amazon-ec2, sftp

#### 前提・実現したいこと

EC2上にあるWordPressのファイル一式をFileZillaでダウンロードし、修正後に再度アップロードしたいです。(これを繰り返し行いたい)

上記記載の事を実現するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

キーペア設定後、接続しようとすると以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
コマンド:       新規ホスト鍵を信用: 1 度だけ
エラー:        Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
エラー:        サーバーに接続できませんでした
```

#### 試したこと

1. EC2管理画面からキーペアを生成
2. 上記キーペアをダウンロード後、自身のPCのデスクトップにフォルダを作ってそこに格納
3. FilleZilla サイトマネージャー「新しいサイト」から新しいファイルを生成
4. 上記ファイルにて下記の通り設定
   プロトコル SFTP
   ホスト IPv4 パブリック IP (数字10桁のやつ)
   ログオンタイプ 鍵ファイル
   ユーザー ec2-user または user でトライしました
   鍵ファイル 2から参照
   ↓
   接続
   ↓
   上記エラーメッセージ

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

macOS High Sierra
FileZilla 3.35.2

色々とググっておりますが、解決策が見つかっておらず困ってます。
初歩的な事で恐縮ですがお答え頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: filezillaで設定してる鍵ファイルの形式はなんですか？pem?ppk?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。参照ファイルは.pemになります。どこかのサイトで.ppkに変更して設定みたいな記事も見ましたが、こちらはやり方が分からず試せておりませんので、.pemでのみ接続を試みただけとなります。

Answer (score 1):

エラーの原因は、キーペアを新しく生成していますが、その場合は公開キーをサーバーの`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`に登録する必要がありますが、それができていないためと思われます。

`filezilla`を使うために新しくキーペアを生成する必要がある場合は殆どなくて`SSH`で`EC2`に接続するために使っているキーペアを使えば大丈夫です。キーペアは`~/.ssh`ディレクイトリの保存している場合が多いと思いますが、隠しディレクトリになので「参照」では表示されませんが直接鍵ファイルの項目に入力するか、"Command + Shift + G"を押してパスを入力できるウィンドウを開いて指定するといいようです。

更にいうと、SSHの方でAWSに接続するための秘密鍵を指定してあると、ログオンタイプを`鍵ファイル`ではなく、`通常`、`パスワードを尋ねる`、`インタラクティブ`のどれかに設定すると自動的に指定されます。SSHは秘密鍵を指定して使う場合が多いと思うので、この設定で大抵の場合は大丈夫です。

Answer (score 0):

> エラー:        Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

FileZillaのことはよくわかりませんが、ssh接続で、秘密鍵のパーミッションが正しくない場合 このエラーが表示されます。

Macの Terminalから秘密鍵ファイルのパーミッションを `0600` に設定してみてください。

例

```
$ chmod 0600 path/to/your.pem
```